# SAS Function to filter out dates

Tags: sas

I'm a beginner to SAS and have been searching for how to filter a data set from a certain date using a function.  I would like to filter out data from December 1st of the previous year to today's date.  I can get what I need with the code below but would like to try to get the same results using a function instead (if possible) and haven't had much success.  Thanks.

```
data getCurrYear;
set k;
if (year(rundt)= year(today())-1 and month(rundt) = 12 )or year(rundt) = year(today()) ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is the `mdy` function.

```
if mdy(12,1,year(today())-1) le rundt;
```

I was trying to come up with a way to make this work with `intck`, which is the function I'd usually use for this sort of purpose, but I don't think it's possible with those rules (Dec 1, Y-1 to Dec 31, Y) with just the one function call.  Dec1-Nov31 would be possible.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure out how to do it using the intck function and was stuck and not successful.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Using intnx...

N.B. When the current date is 01DEC, it will return the same date. If you need the previous 01DEC, simply change `today()` to `today()-1` within the `intnx()` function.

```
if intnx('year1.12',today(),0,'beginning') <= rundt <= today() ;
```

Check logic :

```
data check ;
  do dt = '01dec2012'd to '31dec2013'd by 12 ;
    from_dt = intnx('year1.12',dt,0,'beginning') ;
    output ;
  end ;

  format dt from_dt date9. ;
run ;

       dt      from_dt

01DEC2012    01DEC2012
13DEC2012    01DEC2012
25DEC2012    01DEC2012
06JAN2013    01DEC2012
18JAN2013    01DEC2012
30JAN2013    01DEC2012
11FEB2013    01DEC2012
23FEB2013    01DEC2012
07MAR2013    01DEC2012
19MAR2013    01DEC2012
31MAR2013    01DEC2012
12APR2013    01DEC2012
24APR2013    01DEC2012
06MAY2013    01DEC2012
18MAY2013    01DEC2012
30MAY2013    01DEC2012
11JUN2013    01DEC2012
23JUN2013    01DEC2012
05JUL2013    01DEC2012
17JUL2013    01DEC2012
29JUL2013    01DEC2012
10AUG2013    01DEC2012
22AUG2013    01DEC2012
03SEP2013    01DEC2012
15SEP2013    01DEC2012
27SEP2013    01DEC2012
09OCT2013    01DEC2012
21OCT2013    01DEC2012
02NOV2013    01DEC2012
14NOV2013    01DEC2012
26NOV2013    01DEC2012
08DEC2013    01DEC2013
20DEC2013    01DEC2013
```

Comment: Does it? See code/output added above. The only 'edge-case' is 01DEC - OP needs to clarify scenario where current date = 01DEC

Comment: Ok - re-read the OP's post, you're right. I can be done with nested `intnx()` functions, but not a single function.